# Insert Own Siri Shortcut like Paytm

Tags: ios, swift, sirikit, sirishortcuts

how to insert our own siri shortcut directly into app like Paytm or Whats App. As I want to create inbuilt siri shortcut like Paytm shown in [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z71Xo.jpg)

Comment: As far as I know that's not possible with Siri Shortcuts. You can do it with "normal" Intents only, not custom.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion. will you provide me any stuff how to do with "normal" intents.

Comment: It's a whole world... :)
https://www.appcoda.com/sirikit-introduction/

Comment: @DungeonDev thank you..